# Does Bluetooth App still work and collect data when phone is sleep

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, mobile-application, smartphone

I'm building an Android app for a smart watch that reads the smart watch data.

But the app relies on Bluetooth to connect with the watch.

I want to track heart rate for a day or two.

Is it possible for the the app to lose connection or stop collecting data over the course of 48 hours? When the phone "goes to sleep" or the display screen shuts down?